# What to use if an array is too small in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

In java, an array can have at most Integer.MAX_VALUE items as it uses integers as keys for the array.
What is the best Object to use when I want to use a long as an index?

For example, if I want to calculate all prime numbers below 5 billion using a prime sieve, I cannot use an array as 5000000000 is too large to store in an integer.

Comment: use one of map implementations like HashMap

Comment: Well, you could try List() or ArrayList(). If the list has to contain unique items then better to use a Set(). If you want to identify the items in your array with a unique id, use a Map().

Comment: @OSryx:  You can't use a long to create an array length, though.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections

Comment: Maps, list, sets - all wrong, they internally use an array and therefore also cannot contain more than Integer.MAX_VALUE values. There are some libraries that allow you to do this, but I would ask OP whether he's sure he can hold so many obects in his memory...

Comment: Why not a list of lists? When you exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE just create a new list. Its not pretty, but im going to speculate that there is no pretty way to do this

Comment: Or better yet, a linked list

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459643/using-a-long-as-arraylist-index-in-java

Comment: @Slanec: Only **some** implementations of maps, sets, and lists use arrays. Most don't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but the common API for `get()` etc. usually needs an `integer` index.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Which is a completely different issue from what Slanec raised. And unlike that one, yours is valid -- for lists. Maps, of course, don't have that issue. Now, there may be several reasons not to use Maps for this, but "they internally use an array" isn't one of them.

Answer (score 8):

A sieve of 5000000000 elements does not need an array of 5,000,000,000 values; it needs 5,000,000,000 *bits*. Unfortunately, `BitSet` uses an `int` index as well, but you can implement your own bit set by allocating `5000000000 / 32` integers, and then using bit operations to access the corresponding bit:

- Use `long` as the actual position `pos`
- The location of the `int` inside the `int` array is `(int)(pos / 32)`
- The location of the bit inside the `int` is `(int)(pos % 32)`

Anther approach would be to switch to *segmented sieve*, which reduces memory requirements to √N. A good explanation of how that works is given [here](http://primesieve.org/segmented_sieve.html).

Comment: There are just about `5.15e8` prime numbers smaller than 5 billion, so does it matter?

Comment: @user35443 Sieve implementation needs full 5B indexes, even though the "crossing table" would be much smaller.