# get() from a List, but passing long as argument in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get an element from a list `List<Class> listofitems`, and I have a globale variable `position` of type `long`. I would like to perform `listofitems.get(position)` but it doesnt allow me to do so since `get` takes `int` as argument. If I want to keep the type of `position` as `long`, if there are any other way to do this? (any other way besides casting `position` to `int`)?

Comment: What is the problem in casting the `position` field to `int` when needed?

Comment: A Java List cannot contain more elements as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` anyway. Either cast to int or use a custom list type.

Comment: Just do `.get((int)position);`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri He could of course do that, but it begs the question, perhaps they actually intend to store a list of greater than 2^31 elements, where such a cast would be fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this, you'd have to construct a class that holds a grouping of lists to represent your data. You can write your own access method that splits your long into smaller ints, to access the right position in your list.

See this answer: [Using a long as ArrayList index in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459643/using-a-long-as-arraylist-index-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is a point where memory must be consulted through the `Unsafe` api. Incase of list/arrays greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` [here](http://www.omsn.de/blog/big-arrays-in-java) is the link.
 **NOTE:**

Write your own implementation of the list/array.

`Unsafe` is literally unsafe.

Such an implementation would require long indices.

Speed will abundant.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a `List<Class>`, and it cannot be changed to another type, then there is nothing you can do besides convert that `long` to an `int`.  There is no way to take an arbitrary `List` and call `get` with anything but an `int`.